# How can I prove the correctness of my greatest common divisor progam?

Tags: python

I need to write a program that prints the greatest common divisor of two entered integers, and also prove the correctness of it. I wrote the following:

```
def main():

    x = int(input("Enter the first integer: "))
    y = int(input("Enter the second integer: "))
    print(gcd(x,y))

def gcd(x,y):
    if x > y:
        smaller  = y
    else:
        smaller = x

    for i in range(1, smaller + 1):
        if ((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            gcd = i

    return gcd

main()
```

The precondition is clearly that `x` and `y` should be two integers. The postcondition is the greatest common divisor of `x` and `y`. I need to identify the loop invariant, and show that it is ok after initialization, that it remains true after every iteration. Also, I'm suppose to prove the postcondition by using the loop invariant and show that the loop is finite.

I think the loop invariant is that `i` is always smaller or equal to `x` and `y`, and that `x % i = r` and `y % i = s` for some integers `r` and `s`. This clearly holds for every iteration. The loop continues until `r = 0` and `s = 0`, and then it terminates. Finiteness is guaranteed because the iteration has an upper bound.

Is my reasoning correct here? Does this proves the correctness of the loop?

Comment: just run the code with some test values. I don't think you have a real question here!

Comment: He *does* have a question, but it's a mathematical one, not a programming one.

Comment: uhm i think i have to disagree with you @CollinD, the if statement does not break the for loop so `gcd` will keep on getting bigger as greater divisors are found

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should probably be on the Math StackExchange network, because it is seeking a mathematical proof.

Comment: Try entering negative integers. Your function will crash.

Comment: No, my question is a programming one. Mathematicians won't know what I mean by a loop invariant etc.

Comment: To identify a loop invariant, there must be an loop invariant. While your algorithm might work correctly, it might not have an invariant, or it might have a very non-obvious one. The usual approach for strictly provable correct programs is to develop the proof/algorithm first, and only then implement a program fulfilling/implementing it.

Comment: With large enough numbers you'll get a `MemoryError` in python2.7.  I'll let you know in a few days what happens in python3.5

Comment: take a look here https://gist.github.com/endolith/114336

Answer (score 1):

I think you can state a loop invariant a bit more clearly if you initialize the `gcd` variable to `1` before entering the loop (which be over a range starting at `2` if you want). Your invariant will be:

> `gcd` is the largest integer less than or equal to `i` such that `x % gcd == y % gcd == 0`.

Your loop ends because `i` iterates over a finite range (ending with `i == min(x, y)`). The postcondition is that `gcd` is the greatest common divisor of `x` and `y`, which is proved by the loop invariant (as long as you can prove the GCD of two numbers is not larger than the smaller of them).